# Как поменять шапку сайта в ucoz шаблоне?

Tags: html, css, ucoz

Здравствуйте!

У меня такой вопрос. Мне нужно сделать сайт на uCoz. Решил упростить задачу - делаю через шаблон. Может быть, кто-нибудь есть "в теме", о том как поменять шапку сайта, шаблон сайта #1081? Ну никак не выходит. В таблице стилей CSS не могу найти даже эту картинку. Пробовал в "Проинспектировать элемент" - он есть, я даже могу заменить картинку на свою, но она не сохраняется.

[image]

Comment: @Snaut, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил построить себе дом. Решил упростить задачу и просто купить дом на колесах. Помогите заменить на нем крышу, никак не получается. Почему люди считают, что программирование в целом и создание решений для web в частности - это просто? Почему пытаются самостоятельно делать неизветную, непонятную и новую для них работу?

По теме - помотрите, где находится элемент в инспекторе в Chrome. Там указано, в каком файле находятся таблицы стилей, в которых описан ваш элемент (шапка сайта).

Посмотрел ваш скриншот.

Адрес картинки указан непосредственно в html коде, не в стилях. Если ucoz позволяет, то меняйте код страницы. Если нет - ищите в настройках страницы на ucoz.

Comment: Спасибо! Обучение методом тыка (проб и ошибок) - тоже обучение) я вообще не рассчитывал, что мне ответят.

Comment: А, так вы учитесь, тогда извините. Я не рекомендую учиться на ucoz. Воьмите notepad, документацию по html и попробуйте сделать страничку самостоятельно. Будет что-то непонятно - спрашивайте.